# Error trying to get ordered results from SQL on Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to learn some SQL basic in Python. I encountered an error while trying to get ordered data from the database. When I use ORDER BY it returns the error Exception has occurred: OperationalError
near "WHERE": syntax error. When I remove the WHERE statement, the ORDER BY works. What am I doing wrong?

```
from ast import Return
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

# importing iris dataset from sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
 
# Loading iris dataset
data = load_iris()
 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)

conn = sqlite3.connect('''C:/Users/juran_x1nmlrv/Database/names.db''')
print("ok")

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM NamesTable ORDER BY frequency_group DESC
                WHERE classification = "F"
                    AND group_name LIKE "%A%";''')

NamesTable_df =pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
NamesTable_df.columns = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
print(NamesTable_df)
```

Comment: ORDER BY goes after WHERE. https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-order-of-operations/#:~:text=Six%20Operations%20to%20Order%3A%20SELECT,developer%20to%20know%20this%20order.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks.